# How to improve NSTextStorage addAttribute performance

Tags: ios, swift, textkit, nstextstorage

I have a long text (probably usual book like >200 pages) in `NSTextStorage`. 
I'm distributing this text for textContainers this way:

```
let textStorageLength = defaultTextStorage?.length ?? 0
while layoutManager!.textContainer(forGlyphAt: textStorageLength - 1, 
                                   effectiveRange: nil) == nil {
  let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: textContainerSize)
  layoutManager!.addTextContainer(textContainer)
  pagesCount += 1
}
```

Then I use this containers for textViews on pageViewController.

I have some words marking like:

```
func selectTappableWordsFromList(_ list: [PositionWithWord]) {
  self.defaultTextStorage?.beginEditing()

  list.forEach {
    if !self.shouldInterruptCurrentProcesses {
      self.markWordInDefaultTextStorage(positionWithWord: $0)
    } else {
      self.shouldInterruptCurrentProcesses = false
      self.defaultTextStorage?.endEditing()

      return
    }
  }

  self.defaultTextStorage?.endEditing()
}


 func markWordInDefaultTextStorage(positionWithWord: PositionWithWord) {
    let range = NSMakeRange(positionWithWord.position!.start, 
                            positionWithWord.position!.length)

    defaultTextStorage?.addAttributes(defaultAttributes, range: range)
 }

 let defaultAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
    .underlineColor: UIColor.BookReader.underline
 ]
```

**The problem is**: marking words in whole text storage is working very slow. The more pages in the book, the slower it works.

Also screenshot of cpu usage from profiler.

[image]

Any way to improve logic?

Comment: @matt I already have

Comment: @matt Sorry, updated question

Comment: @matt I'll really appreciate for any help, cause I've no more ideas actually. I've optimized it as much as I can